# Running OpenCV in Mac OS terminal with opencv_contrib

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile and run OpenCV through the command line. I can get the main Open CV libraries to work however I think my problem is with using the opencv_contrib libraries.

I have installed Open CV with home brew.

I can compile and run the below code fine from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927294/running-opencv-3-in-mac-terminal):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        Mat src = Mat(Size(320,240),CV_64F);;
        namedWindow("test");

        cout << "press any key to close" << endl;

        while(true){
                randn(src,0,1.0);
                imshow("test",src);
                if(waitKey() > 0) break;
        }
}
```

This is compiled like this:

```
g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -o cv
```

Then ran ./main

[image]

However when I try and run anything with the opencv_contrib libraries I get this error when compiled like this:

```
g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -o cv
```

error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in cv-f48298.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I believe this is likely due to not specifying the opencv_contrib libraries. I understand they come installed with homebrew. In my Cellar directory I have a directory for opencv and opencv_contrib. I'm not sure if the opencv_contrib directory needs to be located within the opencv directory.

But I believe everything is there as with this:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv
```

It outputs:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
```

But then if I add that to my command like:

```
g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv -o cv
```

I get this:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: unsupported option '--cflags'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv'
```

I'm able to compile the same code in Xcode and I only needed to add the search paths for the openCV directory and add the libs within there. I can run the code by opening the products folder in finder and running `./cv` with images passed in. But I'm struggling with doing this all through the command line.

Any help would be great!

Comment: when you installed opencv with homebrew, did you use the `--with-contrib` option?

Comment: Yes. I also can compile in Xcode fine by linking in other linker flags. Linking in `-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include/opencv` , `-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib` , `-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include` and adding all the 3.41 lib files in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib`

Comment: it worked fine for me, using cmake to build with the command `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` and later `target_link_libraries(myproject ${OpenCV_LIBS})`

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the **output** of the `pkgconfig` tool (you listed it above: `-I/usr/local/include/opencv ...`) to your compilation command line to compile correctly.

You could just manually copy this output text into your compiler invocation command:

```
g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -o cv
```

This is usually automated by calling pkgconfig inline:

```
g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o cv
```

Notice the backticks in this though - they are missing in your command line. With the backticks `pkgconfig` will be executed and the output (which you know what it looks like) will be inserted into the command line.

Comment: If I run: `g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o cv`. I get: clang: error: unsupported option '--libs'
clang: error: unsupported option '--cflags'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '`pkg-config'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'opencv`' `

Comment: Or If I use `g++ cv.cpp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/include" -L"/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_5/lib/" -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -o cv` I get the error above related to `"cv::xfeatures2d::SURF`

Comment: For the SURF features you need the OpenCV contrib package, which is installed with homebrew by using the `--with-contrib` flag, see e.g. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

Comment: I've already got the OpenCV contrib package. I have both directories in my Cellar directory as I stated above. I can also compile in Xcode. So I have the the SURF features. Are they going to be in a different location and therefore have to link differently?

Comment: It seems you have several OpenCV versions installed. The Homebrew one at `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv` (which you say has xfeatures_2d). But I just noticed that the output of `pkgconfig` finds another OpenCV installation at `/usr/local/include`. Either fix your linking issue by manually adding `-lopencv_xfeatures2d` to your command line, or maybe uninstall the global OpenCV version so your pkgconfig finds the homebrew one.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that what I had linked in Xcode was far less than was outputted in. `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` I added all of them and now compiles with all libraries added. Your explanation makes sense, thanks. I'll look at deleting the other one.